# Displaying a hidden div menu from a list

Tags: html, hide, show

Sorry If this is simple but I need some help with my navigation bar. I can't seem to be able to toggle to show/hide the div with the click of a link. My code is here. This is just some a basic format as I want the right functionality before adding it to my website. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
#submenu ul{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('submenu').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li id="submenu" onclick="showDiv()";><a href="#"> Hi</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"> Hi2</a>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So in this example I want the hidden div to show Hi2 once I click Hi1. I don't mind using JQuery or Javascript I just need a way around this. I've made other navigation menus's however they were horizontal and usually worked by hover menus. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Look that You've been missing a <body> tag just after the head..,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 $('#submenu').click(function() {
  $('#submenu ul').toggle('');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wFN9t/6/)**

---

If you dont want to toggle then use

```
$('#submenu').click(function() {
  $('#submenu ul').css('display','block');
});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wFN9t/7/)**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the great share. Do you think you could take a look at my fiddle if I made one? It's not working for my larger code. Thanks

Comment: Include documnet.ready in your code and proper doc/meta type. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/wFN9t/8/

Comment: So this is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/KgCYE/7/. The div is being hidden, but nothing happens when I click the projects tab. I know the content is there because if you remove the display:none, the content is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv() {
  $("#submenu ul").css("display","block");
}
</script>
```